# How to create a file format of TSV in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have to create TSV file in snowflake.

If anyone knows could you please share the sample code.

Answer (score 3):

Using a comma is so common for delimited files, the term for any delimited file format in Snowflake is CSV. You can create a TSV file format by specifying a type of CSV and a delimiter of tab:

```
CREATE FILE FORMAT TSV_FILE_FORMAT TYPE = 'CSV' COMPRESSION = 'AUTO'
FIELD_DELIMITER = '\t' RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n' SKIP_HEADER = 0
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = 'NONE' TRIM_SPACE = FALSE 
ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE ESCAPE = 'NONE' 
ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\134' DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO' 
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO' NULL_IF = ('\\N');
```

Your specific parameters may vary depending on the specific way the TSV handles things like escaping tab characters, etc., but this is a good start.

Comment: Note that many of these settings specified here are the default. The only ones you'd actually need are: `TYPE`, `FIELD_DELIMITER`, and `ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD`